# Error when instaling Openfst Thrax [configure: error: fst/fst.h header not found]

Tags: linux, ubuntu, named-entity-recognition, openfst

I tried to install Thrax on Ubuntu using `./configure --enable-far=true --enable-pdt=true --enable-mpdt=true`, but the following error shows

```
checking fst/fst.h usability... no
checking fst/fst.h presence... no
checking for fst/fst.h... no
configure: error: fst/fst.h header not found
```

I tried `./configure --enable-far=true --enable-pdt=true --enable-mpdt=true --enable-fst=true`, but the error persists

I also tried to set `CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib`, but same error occurs.

How shall I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Quote: <sub>./configure --enable-far=true --enable-pdt=true
>   --enable-mpdt=true</sub>

... that's configure options for openfst.

```
tar xvf openfst-1.7.6.tar.gz
cd openfst-1.7.6/
./configure --prefix=/usr --libexecdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-far=true --enable-pdt=true --enable-mpdt=true
make
sudo make install
```

I.e. with `prefix=/usr` the libraries / headers are found automatically by thrax.

```
tar xvf thrax-1.3.2.tar.gz
cd thrax-1.3.2/
./configure
make && sudo make install
```

Results, package examples (for Ubuntu 19.04 and later)  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1EHvwKt5X54faPT6SKQGkVHWgeUcPIrob?usp=sharing

Other test builds, openfst / thrax : Ubuntu 16.04.6 and 18.04.4 → no errors.